# numpy.where() function throws a FutureWarning, returns scalar instead of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am currently working with NumPy version 1.12.1, and every call to `numpy.where()` returns an empty list with the following warning:

```
FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
```

I am comparing a string, `date_now` and a list, `dates_list`:

```
np.where(date_now==dates_list)
```

This causes errors, as the program subsequently calls functions that expect the numpy.where() output to be a non-empty. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you using `numpy.where`?

Comment: Is `date_now` a list or NumPy array?  If it is the former, try `np.where(np.array(dates_list)==date_now)`.  Otherwise, you are testing the truth value of the entire `dates_list` as a single object versus a string.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have initialized a string `date_now`  and a list `dates_list`, and I am creating a variable `temp = numpy.where(dates_list==date_now)`

Comment: @BradSolomon your solution seemed to work. Still wondering what the future warning means though. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the actual values that caused the future warning? What is `type(date_now)` and `type(dates_list)`? Brad's answer doesn't trigger it

Comment: @Eric `date_now` is a string, and `type(dates_list)` is `numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: What is `dates_list.dtype` and `dates_list.shape`?

Comment: And be explicit - is `date_now` a `str` or `np.str_`?

Comment: @Eric it's just a `str`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current comparison, you are comparing the entire list object, `dates_list`, to a string, `date_now`.  This will cause element-wise comparison to fail and return a scalar as if you are just comparing two scalar values:

```
date_now = '2017-07-10'    
dates_list = ['2017-07-10', '2017-07-09', '2017-07-08']    
np.where(dates_list==date_now, True, False)
Out[3]: array(0)
```

What you want is to declare `dates_list` as a NumPy array to facilitate element-wise comparison.

```
np.where(np.array(dates_list)==date_now, True, False)
Out[8]: array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```